# Passing data from parent to child using react.State but State reset to initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am facing an issue while passing the state to the child component, so basically I am getting customer info from `child1(Home)` and saving in the parent `state(App)` and it works fine.

And then I am passing the updated `state(basketItems)` to `child2(Basket)`. But when I click on the **Basket** button  the basket page doesn't show any info in `console.log(basketItems)` inside the basket page and the chrome browser(console) looks refreshed too.

Any suggestion why it is happening and how can I optimize to pass the data to `child2(basket)` from main (APP).

**update:2**
i have tired to simulated the code issue in sand box with the link below, really appreciate for any advise about my code in codesandbox (to make it better) as this is the first time i have used it

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-tharp-j79dq?file=/src/App.js)

**Update:1**
i have made a small clip on youtube just to understand the issue i am facing
[basketItems goes back to initial state](https://youtu.be/Il2DeZ1Ujfs)

```
Main (APP)___|
             |_Child 1(Home)
             |_Child 2 (Basket)
```

Snippet from `Parent main(App)` component

```
function App() {

const [basketItems, setBasketItems] = useState([]);

const addBasketitems = (product, quantity) => {
    setBasketItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, { ...product, quantity }])
 }
console.log(basketItems) // here i can see the updated basketItems having customer data as expected [{...}]

return (
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <header className="header">
        <Nav userinfo={userData} userstatus={siginalready} />
      </header>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => (


          <Home {...props} userData={userData} userstatus={siginalready}
            addBasketitems={addBasketitems}
          />
        )}
        />
        <Route path="/basket" exact render={(props) =>
          (<Basket {...props} basketItems={basketItems} />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

Snippet from the `child(basket)`

```
function Basket({basketItems}) {

console.log(basketItems) // here i only get the [] and not the cusotmer data from parent component
  return (
  <div>
   {`${basketItems}`} // here output is blank
  </div>

    );
}

export default Basket;
```

Snippet from the `child(Home)`

... here once the button is pressed it will pass the userselected details to parent

```
....
<Button name={producNumber} value={quantities[productName]} variant="primary"
  onClick={() => {
    addBasketitems(eachproduct, quantities[productName])
  }}>
  Add to Basket
     </Button >
```

Comment: Can you try and create a codesandbox to reproduce your error?

Comment: Hi Arpitha, to be honest i have never used codesandbox before, but let me try if i can. i can also give you the link for the project-code on Github if that helps. https://github.com/rock-007/Java-HTML-Project/blob/master/ec-client/src/App.js

Comment: Creating codesandbox is very easy, it will provide you with the template of react if you create a React Codesandbox, And you just need to focus on the code that you can bring from your local codebase. In case of using additional dependency, just add this by clicking on 'Add dependency'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works fine, the reason your output in addbasketItem does not change is the when using setState it takes some time to apply the changes and if you use code below you can see the result.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('basket:',basketItems)
  },[basketItems])
```

Your Basket component only renders once so replace it with this code and see if it works:

```
function Basket({ basketItems }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(basketItems);
  }, [basketItems]);
  return <div>{`${items}`}</div>;
}
```

but for passing data between several components, I strongly suggest that you use provided it is much better.

Comment: Thanks ErfanFi79,i can see the console.log(basketItems) in the parent(App) component so it is updating the state, but cant see it in the child2(basket) component (when passing from parent to child) even if i use useEffect in child component.

Comment: no its the same mate. it looks to me that when i go to basket,  the App component initialises  before even passing the state to Basket  and thats why i think in Basket in am getting the initial state of basketItems i.e  [ ]